# "If condition" in python does not set the value given to it when pressed "Enter"

Tags: python-3.x

Two input is enough for the program to run but for rare occations third input C is used, but other time depending upon the length of A and B the C value is set.

```
A = int(input("Enter A:"))
B = int(input("Enter B:"))
tempC = input("Enter C:(If None press Enter)")
C = ""

counter1 = len(str(A))
counter2 = len(str(B))

print("counter value is:" + str(counter1)+ " and " + str(counter2))
print("temp value is:" + str(tempC))

if counter1 == counter2:
    if tempC and (counter1 == 1):
        C = "10"
    elif tempC and (counter1 == 2):
        C = "100"
    elif tempC and (counter1 == 3):
        C = "1000"
else:
    print("Lengths are not same")

print("Value of C is: " + str(C))
```

Output Expected- when enter is pressed and counter1 = 2

```
Enter A:45
Enter B:54
Enter C:(If None press Enter)
counter value is:2 and 2
temp value is:
Value of C is: 100
```

Obtained output

```
Enter A:45
Enter B:45
Enter C:(If None press Enter)
counter value is:2 and 2
temp value is:
Value of C is:
```

Comment: You should check which part of the condition fails - `tempC == None` or `counter == 2` or both. We cannot guess what you have inputted to your program.

Comment: What is `counter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try:

`if tempC=="" and (counter1 == 2):`

This should fix your problem.

Also, C is already a string, so you can simply use `C` instead of `str(C)`.

So, your code as per your edit is:

```
A = int(input("Enter A:"))
B = int(input("Enter B:"))
tempC = input("Enter C:(If None press Enter)")
C = ""

counter1 = len(str(A))
counter2 = len(str(B))

print("counter value is:" + str(counter1)+ " and " + str(counter2))
print("temp value is:" + str(tempC))

if counter1 == counter2:
    if tempC=="" and (counter1 == 1):
        C = "10"
    elif tempC=="" and (counter1 == 2):
        C = "100"
    elif tempC=="" and (counter1 == 3):
        C = "1000"
    elif tempC=="" and (counter1 == 4):
        C = "10000"
else:
    print("Lengths are not same")


print("Value of C is: " + str(C))
```